# Cypress test runner intermittent ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4200

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm having intermittent issues running some automated e2e tests written in Cypress. Apparently I'm the only one having this issue so it might be isolated to my laptop. The strange thing is it happens intermittently.

When I run the tests and cypress tries to browse to our app I get the following error:

`CypressError
cy.visit() failed trying to load:

http://localhost:4200/

We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.

We received this error at the network level:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4200

Common situations why this would fail:

- you don't have internet access
- you forgot to run / boot your web server
- your web server isn't accessible
- you have weird network configuration settings on your computer`

If I open a new tab in the instance of Chrome that is controlled by Cypress I also get the same error.

If I open a standard instance of Chrome (not controlled by Cypress) the page loads fine.

The really weird thing is I can put money if I try again in a couple of hours it will just start working.

Anyone got any hunches on this one because I'm clueless or not sure how to debug.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, It seems to bug-out when I have a cy.request() to a different url before I perform a cy.visit().

Comment: I'm having this problem too. I've been googling for ages and there doesn't seem to be a solution.

Comment: I have the very same issue :( I verified very (very) often that the server is running, etc.

Answer (score 7):

I stumbeled over an answer to this issue. I have no idea why, but for me this appeared from one day to another. From working *everywhere* to working *nowhere*, except for CI builds which is even stranger.

The answer that helped me was to pass `--host 0.0.0.0` to the angular server I'm testing against. I have no idea why `127.0.0.1` is not regarded local for me (and my colleagues with different OSs as well) anymore, but it just seems to be like this for some reason.

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me, too. on vite, I have to use 0.0.0.0 as host instead of localhost :/ (cypress still complains that it cannot verify the URL works, but then it works)

Comment: Same here, but `--host 127.0.0.1` also works. You can also update the `angular.json` config file like following:

"projects": {
    "project-name": {
        ...
        "architect": {
            "serve": {
                "options": {
                  "host": "127.0.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. try to run

```
npx cypress open
```

from cmd as administrator.